# replacing in R in groups

Tags: r

I have data.frame like this

`DATE         GROUP  CARD1  CARD2
 01-01-05     123    666    1234 
 02-01-05     123    000    1234 
 03-01-05     123    000    1234
 01-01-05     124    777    2345
 02-01-05     124    000    2345`

And I'd like to replace the zeros in column CARD1 using number that is not 0.

```
DATE         GROUP CARD1   CARD2
01-01-05     123    666    1234
02-01-05     123    666    1234
03-01-05     123    666    1234
01-01-05     124    777    2345
02-01-05     124    777    2345
```

How to achieve that ? :)

Comment: Try `with(d, ave(CARD1, GROUP, FUN = max))` (where `d` is your data set).

Comment: But I don't have NAs

Comment: See updated comment.

Comment: What is Fun? And whats about column card2? I'd like to do replacing in the same groups   GROUP-CARD2

Comment: So you could just do `with(d, ave(CARD1, CARD2, GROUP, FUN = max))` (though it throws warnings for some reason)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `data.table`, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'GROUP' and 'CARD2', we assign (`:=`) 'CARD1' as the values that are not equal to 0 (assuming that there is only a single unique non-zero value per 'GROUP').

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, CARD1 := CARD1[CARD1!=0], by = .(GROUP, CARD2)]
df1
#       DATE GROUP CARD1 CARD2
#1: 01-01-05   123   666  1234
#2: 02-01-05   123   666  1234
#3: 03-01-05   123   666  1234
#4: 01-01-05   124   777  2345
#5: 02-01-05   124   777  2345
```

---

Or we can `order` the 'CARD1' descendingly by 'GROUP' and 'CARD2' and assign 'CARD1' with the first element of 'CARD1'

```
setDT(df1)[order(-CARD1), CARD1 := CARD1[1L] , by = .(GROUP, CARD2)]
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(DATE = c("01-01-05", "02-01-05", "03-01-05", "01-01-05", 
"02-01-05"), GROUP = c(123L, 123L, 123L, 124L, 124L), CARD1 = c(666L, 
 0L, 0L, 777L, 0L), CARD2 = c(1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 2345L, 2345L
 )), .Names = c("DATE", "GROUP", "CARD1", "CARD2"),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: And whats about group CARD2?

Comment: @Agnieszka  I thought there was only one grouping variable 'GROUP'.  Updated the post.

Comment: I will but I cant. :(  I do not have enough points to give You plus. Anyway Im still checking your answer. I have problem, R told me that he cant find column GROUP. CARD1 and CARD2 are characters and GROUP is numeric. Dont know what to do

Comment: Yes, there is. I have only 11 points of reputation. From 15 you can give someone plus for help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what solution you are after. Below is partial solution if you consider your values to be numeric. You can modify for strings etc.

Create a function and then dplyr packaged with group_by and mutate_each to apply the function,get a partial solution.

```
impute_max=function(x){
    x[x==0]=max(x)
    return(x) 
}

df <- data.frame(group=c(123,123,123,124,124),card1=c(666,000,000,777,000))

df2 <- df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate_each(funs(impute_max))
```